# jquery Disable multiple dropdowns on enable checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

A part of my form is a place where users can choose days where they are closed and also the opening hours on days they are open.

I have made a fiddle, this should make it clear.

This form is being generated dynamicly in php because it will need to be multilanguage.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSKH/

I need help on how to disable the dropdowns for a specific day when they click the checkbox for being closed on that day.

Also the values will be posted to a database, any idea how i should disable the values of the dropdowns(the opening hours) when they are not open on that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that every input field (checkboxes, dropdowns...) are created dinamically, so use value attribute of each checkbox to trigger enable/disable action.

I have edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSKH/16/

I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with MooTools, so I wrote a little script using jQuery but I hope that it could be rewritten using MooTools without much hassle.

Btw, I strongly suggest double-quoting all attributes although I think modern browser can handle this without any problems . Also, I'm pretty sure that `for` attribute of `label` is used for element IDs, not names.

I hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Wow thanks for editing the fiddle, the only thing is that the dropdowns need to be disabled once the user selects a day. The opposite of how it is now. Would you mind editing that in the fiddle. I would be very gratefull!!

Comment: I have managed to switch it around and it's working in the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSKH/30/

Any idea why this isnt working in my complete form? Is it because the div is nested into other divs?

Comment: Fixed it,I forgot to add the id for the fieldset. it works in the main form now 2. Thanks alot for the assistance.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was away from computer during the whole day... glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give an `id` to the selectboxes and check boxes and use the disabled attribute to disable the select box as below:

`$('#id').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: Any idea on how to clear/change the value once the dropdowns are disabled?

Comment: `$('#id').find('option').remove()` will remove all the options.

Comment: And if you want to add new values after removing previous ones, try this:  `$('#id').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="val">text</option>');`

Answer (score 0):

you can fire an event on selecting the checkbox and use the above answer as suggested below